# Views in ScrollView doesn't respect constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview

I added a **ScrollView** to my View Controller. Then, I created constraints between my inner elements and the scroll view itself, but I don't understand why my *yellow* view for example is not taking the full width.

Here is the screenshot of my view and constraints:

[image]

And sometimes I get this, why?

[image]

When I don't use Scroll View, all works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control drag from the mapView to the outer main View and select **Equal-Widths**

Comment: Thanks! It works. Why do I need to do this, is it a Xcode "bug"?

Comment: No ,it's not a bug scrollView finds it's width and height from it's subviews not vice versa

Comment: *It's content width and height