# UIView in UIScrollView respects some constraints but not other

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, anchor

I need to add a containerView inside a `UIScrollView`, and then add multiple subviews in the containerView.  For some reason, the containerView does not respect the `top/bottom/left/rightAnchor` constraints, but it works with `width/height/centerX/centerYAnchor`

**NOTE:** If the superview is a `UIView` instead of a `UIScrollView`, it works fine.

The project is 100% code based. Using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4

**This does not work**

```
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

**This works**

```
containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

In both cases the `scrollView.constraints` array includes 4 constraints total.

The interesting thing is that the printout of them is different. Some of the constraints that don't work (.`top` and .`left`) are printed using the *Autolayout Visual Format Language*. Also, note the (LTR) in the third one:

```
ScrollView [
<NSLayoutConstraint:V:|-(0)-[UIView] (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.bottom == UIScrollView.bottom (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:H:|-(0)-[UIView](LTR) (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.right == UIScrollView.right (active)>]
```

The constraints that work are printed as follows:

```
ScrollView [
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.width == UIScrollView.width (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.height == UIScrollView.height (active)>, 
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.centerX == UIScrollView.centerX (active)>, 
<NSLayoutConstraint:UIView.centerY == UIScrollView.centerY (active)>]
```

I researched StackOverflow and found a couple of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708331/views-in-scrollview-doesnt-respect-constraints), but they didn't really help me explain what the problem is (or the `UIScrollView` requirements for constraints).

Any ideas?

Comment: in side scroll view any view have you need to give height or width that require so you can add height and width to the specify archer to the top, bottom, left, and right anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIScrollView needs some contents in it to be scrolled. The view you are adding (inside scrollview), does not have size (height and width), so scroll view can't identify size of its content.

Add size for a view (inside scrollview) and it will work.

```
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
// Size constraints
containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

// To check scrolling of container view; try this
containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor + 50.0).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor + 50.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thx @Krual.  Now I understand why UIScrollView requires the size. Although the whole idea of Autolayout is that if you define the 4 anchors, the size should be inferred (considering the size of the superview).   Or if I define the size of the containerView, I only need 2 anchors (i.e.. .top/.left) to define the geometry of the view.   Also.  If I set the contentSize to a fixed value, it does not work...    Thx....   e

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `UIScrollView` requires it's `contentSize` to be set in some way. By anchoring the `UIView`'s layout to the sides of the `UIScrollView`, auto layout still doesn't have an explicit idea of what `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`.

Since the `UIScrollView` is probably anchored to some parent view, the height and width of the `UIScrollView` is already defined. By giving a `UIView` these constraints, auto layout can determine the size of the `UIView` and then use that size to set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go through the following points in order to use scrollview in your application. 
 1. First add UIScrollview and give it constrain in view(left, right,width,height).[![enter image description here][1]][1]
 2. Now each scrollview has content view which should be there , we cannot add our required views directly to UIScrollview.
 3. Add view to scrollview(we name it content view) , give it top,bottom, left and right constrain. Apart from these we need to add height and width constrain to the content view. 
 4. If you want to have vertical scrollview then give width equal to scrollview and a proper height (like height constrain = 600)or greater than scrollview height.
 5. If you want to have horizontal scrollview then give height equal to scrollview and width greater than actual width of scrollview.
```

Have a look at the constrain of content view added below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Now you should add custom views in view added as child of scrollview.

Comment: Hi @Himan.  Can you please point me to the reference regarding not adding multiple subviews to UIScrollView?.   Apple's documentation refers to the scroll view as the 'content view'.   I am being able to add multiple subviews with different anchors to the scroll view.